# Error on $this->requestAction() in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have this code,

```
while($com_reg_credit){
  foreach($payers as $payer){

    echo $this->requestAction('/admin/add_to_list/' . $payer . '/' . $_SESSION['User']['Team']['id'] . '/?credit=1' );
  }

}
```

what it does is, `while($com_reg_credit){`, it executes the process inside it. I wanted to call the function specifying the `url` but somehow it's not working. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @DavorLozic , yeah, I tried and it still is the same. It won't function.

Comment: using request action is generally avoided unless absolutely necessary. There's probably a better way to do this if you can provide some context and more code~

Comment: @Ross, I have tried using `$this->redirect()` but I want to call the function over and over again before it redirects so using `$this->redirect` is not advisable. What other solutions can you suggest?

Comment: you could adjust your `add_to_list` function to take an array(s) but without knowing what `add_to_list` does, or the format of the data it is hard to help more. and are you doing this in the view or the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try something like this:

*From documentation:*

```
echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'featured'), array('named' => array('limit' => 3)));
echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array(5)));
```

*EDIT:*

```
while($com_reg_credit){
    foreach($payers as $payer){
        echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'add_to_list'), array($payer, $_SESSION['User']['Team']['id'], '?credit1'));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what would exactly my requestAction call look like based on my problem above? I don't quite get the second parameter after the controller and action. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'll try. Look at my answer after few minutes. :)

Comment: Im afraid your solution did not work, it says `missing controller` error. :(

Comment: Well, what is your controller's name? You didn't specified it in your example? I thought that it's 'admin'. :)

Comment: the controller and the action I put are all correct. I don't know why it displays missing controller error.

Comment: Well, you can send me a whole code to my e - mail provided on my profile and I'll try to find the bug. :)